# What is wrong with this line of code to select a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheets("test1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 4)).Select
```

I am getting object-define error for above line of code.
Could someone tell me please what is wrong with it?

Comment: Code is working for me but sheet _test1_  was the active one when I ran it.

Comment: Simply put, you are on a different sheet while this line executes. As a result, `Cells` will refer to cells on that specific sheet instead of test1.